# Why is Jabba's stand-in on the cover of the Star Wars Radio Drama?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

[image]

This person appears to be Declan Mulholland, the *stand-in* from the deleted scene in which Jabba the Hutt was meant to appear:

[image]

> Mulholland would have been **replaced** with a stop-motion creature during post-production had the scene not ended up on the cutting room floor. 
>   <sub>- [source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_Desilijic_Tiure#Behind_the_scenes)</sub>

The look for the stand-in was never canon; Jabba was never going to look like the that. 
***Why* does his face appear on the *official* Radio Drama cover if he was just *standing-in for where Jabba was meant to appear*?**

Comment: Wow, interesting..

Comment: -1 for circle isn't red. /s

Answer (score 29, accepted):

## Heater

In the Radio Drama, Jabba's lines from spaceport scene in *A New Hope* were kept but given to a humanoid character named ["Heater"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heater) — this is described, for instance, in [*A Brief Guide to Star Wars*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=i9jABAAAQBAJ&pg=PT77&lpg=PT77&dq=star+wars+radio+drama+heater&source=bl&ots=qLxSsiD_CX&sig=aeCy1LVNfr6X4xV7vQH87-UGE4w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwr-7IjcTJAhWMj4MKHQZeAdcQ6AEIKjAH#v=onepage&q=star%20wars%20radio%20drama%20heater&f=false) by Brian J. Robb.  For the cover artwork, Mulholland's likeness was used, given that he was the human giving those same lines in the unused footage.

Heater also appeared in *Star Wars: The Essential Guide to Characters*. The *Essential Guide* sketch reaffirmed Heater's look as being that of Declan Mulholland from his stand-in portrayal of Jabba.

[image]

In short, "Heater" was a retcon name given to Declan Mulholland's "Jabba", and this became part of the Radio Drama.  The cover reflects this.

Comment: Wow... That's amazing

Answer (score 15):

[This interview](https://randymartinez.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/art-focus-official-star-wars-a-new-hope-radio-drama-cd-cover/) with Randy Martinez, the picture's illustrator has confirmed that the character depicted is "[Heater](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Heater)", a high-ranking henchman of Jabba the Hutt.

> *The character on the right with the
> crazy hair is Heater. No, that’s his name… Heater. Truth be told, he
> was Jabba in the original script. They [actually shot these Jabba
> scenes with the actor who depicted in my painting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Sf4eb9l__4). Several years
> later, Lucasfilm reinserted the confrontation scene Han Solo has with
> Jabba the Hutt outside of the Millenium Falcon, but put a CG Jabba the
> Hut over the actor who portrayed Jabba in the original filming.*
>
> *By
> 1981, when the Radio Drama was produced, Lucasfilm had already started
> developing Jabba the Hutt for Return of the Jedi. As we all know Jabba
> is a big slimy slug-like Hutt, and does not speak English.  To patch
> this continuity problem, Lucasfilm changed the name of the Jabba
> character to Heater for the Radio Drama. But then, in the movies he
> went back to being Jabba the Hutt for the Special Edition… I know it’s
> confusing, but Heater, for all intents and purposes, is Jabba the
> Hutt.*

Comment: This makes that SE scene even more painful. We could've had a new character instead of all that horrible CG.